# Can not read date columns correctly via xlsx

Tags: r

I am using R-package (xlsx) in order to read data from xlsx via read.xlsx. Unfortunately i have got a problem reading correctly xlsx date columns as they are defined in xlsx via Cell Format displayed below.

[image]

[image]

Is there any idea for this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

After reading in the xlsx file use `as.Date` function with the `origin` argument. The origin date in excel is 30 of December 1899

```
as.Date(your date column, origin = "1899-12-30")
```